# How to put green background color green in the whole calendar in fullcalendar.io?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am developing an application where I have implemented full calendar(http://fullcalendar.io/). I have show available and non available slots. By default, all the slots should be available. So I have rendered events as red coloured in the slots to show them as 'not available' .

But how do I background colour all the other slots in the calendar to green without showing any events in them?

**UPDATE**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/craigcav/uKCbX/) `is the jsfiddle for fullcalendar.io.`

I want to make all slots background color green.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddler.net

Comment: sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/craigcav/uKCbX/

Comment: you need to use appropriate theme for that, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/uKCbX/288/ .

Comment: thats not correct, I only want to make the slots green, not the entire theme green

Comment: well, if you want to customize it more than the theme, then you need to tweak the library, which doesnt seem easy . there are possible predefined themes , which you can check here, http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {

    cell.css("background-color", "green");

}
```